# Finding proper intercepts of a square root function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Apologies for not knowing how to insert the proper math symbols - new to the forum.

The problem asks to find the $x$ and $y$ intercepts of $y=\sqrt{x+49}$. Solving easily yields the $x$-intercept at $-49$, but setting $x$ to zero yields $y$-intercepts of $+7$ and $-7$. Of course, graphing the function clearly shows that the $-7$ value is NOT in this function, as the graph begins at $(-49,0)$ and continues on a positive slope, crossing the y-axis at $+7$, and continuing to infinity.

My issue is the software being used is forcing me to write the y-intercept at $+7$ and $-7$. It is ALEKS, if anyone is familiar with the program. Is this an AI glitch, or am I off in my assertion?

Comment: Please learn [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) then edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

$7$ is the only $y$-intercept.

$y=\sqrt{x+49} \ge 0$.

They are confusing the equality with $y^2=x+49$.